# prevent onblur event in input type=text called by certain key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have material ui input type search in my React app and I have a problem with typing key 'с' **in russian keyboard** on it. When I type this key it calls `onblur` event and goes out of focus and value not changes. All other key works correctly and if trying to type on other language key with same code works fine. If add onkeydown event it fires same events for all keys, nothing difference

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-frnr9?file=/demo.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Menu } from "@material-ui/core";
import { FormControl, OutlinedInput } from "@material-ui/core";

// элементы фильтра
const Demo = () => {
  const initialSearchState = {
    searchValue: "",
    isOpened: false,
    anchorEl: null,
    canClose: true,
    className: "newmonitoring-th"
  };

  const [filterSearchState, setSearchFilter] = useState(initialSearchState);

  // обработчки кнопки
  const handleClick = e => {
    const newAnchorEl = e.currentTarget;
    const newIsOpened = !filterSearchState.isOpened;
    setSearchFilter({
      ...filterSearchState,
      anchorEl: newAnchorEl,
      isOpened: newIsOpened
    });
  };

  // обработчик закрытия
  const handleClose = () => {
    const newIsOpened = !filterSearchState.isOpened;
    setSearchFilter({
      ...filterSearchState,
      isOpened: newIsOpened,
      anchorEl: null
    });
    return;
  };
  const handleSearch = e => {
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;
    setSearchFilter({
      ...filterSearchState,
      searchValue: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>Menu</div>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={filterSearchState.anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={filterSearchState.isOpened}
        onClose={handleClose}
        data-filter={"dataFilter"}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "left" }}
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "left" }}
      >
        <div className="filter__filterBlock">
          <span className="filter__label" variant="overline" display="">
            Сортировка
          </span>

          <span className="filter__label" variant="overline" display="">
            Фильтр
          </span>
          <div className="filter__filterSearch">
            <FormControl variant="outlined">
              <OutlinedInput
                type="text"
                placeholder="Значение"
                variant="outlined"
                color="secondary"
                onChange={handleSearch}
                value={filterSearchState.searchValue}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you show your implementation

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: You need to add ` onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to the `div`.

Comment: thanks you, it helps